# Should procedure return value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Should procedure return value in MYSQL?

I have procedure that checks order and changes status by some conditions.

Depends of condition result status can be difference also.

How to return back result code? Or specific message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not you make use of a `Function` in order to return some value as this is the basic difference between a procedure and function plus if you still want to return some value you can use a OUT parameter in the procedure declaration and have that value set in the procedure finally use that value via bind variable.

Comment: Can I create store function like a procedure?

Comment: @OPV yes for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete guide to procedures on MySql:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php

Comment: old stuff even is the document is update this year.. it seams it's based on MySQL 5.6